# get data series with value in another data series python

Tags: python, pandas

i am want to get some data from 1 data series use value from another data series. for example :

```
dat1 = {'test1':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'],
      'test2':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],'test3'
      [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]}
dat2 = {'param':['q','a','z','b','o']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dat1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dat2)
```

and data i want to get looks like :

```
dat3 = {'test1':['a','b'],'test2':[1,2],'test3':[10,11]}
```

that just example, the data real have more than 1200 rows x 5 columns for the first data series and 5000 rows x 2 columns for the second data series.
ps : extension of my data is csv and sep is ","

Comment: What is the use of `dat2` in creating `dat3`? Do you only want to select some rows from `df1`?

Comment: What's really your question, from here, why not: `{k:v[:2] for k,v in df1.to_dict('list').items()}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `query`

```
df1.query('test1 in @df2.param')

  test1  test2  test3
0     a      1     10
1     b      2     11
```

---

#### `isin`

```
df1[df1.test1.isin(df2.param)]

  test1  test2  test3
0     a      1     10
1     b      2     11
```

---

#### `numpy.in1d`

```
df1[np.in1d(df1.test1, df2.param)]

  test1  test2  test3
0     a      1     10
1     b      2     11
```